# Eclipse RCP - Updating IStatusLineManager

Tags: eclipse-rcp, workbench

Anybody knows how to update **IStatusLineManager** outside **ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor**?

I tried following approach but it throws NullPointerException

```
IStatusLineManager statusLine =  platformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
statusLine.setMessage("Test Message");
```

I even tried to execute it from:

```
display.asyncExec(...)
```

But same result: **NullPointerException** on ***getStatusLineManager()***

Answer (score 1):

Except for a few very rare cases, the `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` always is a singleton, so usually you can just save a copy in the class and access it via a static method.

Comment: I thought about this too, I will try it that way. But I would better use some smarter solution like services etc. if possible

Comment: I just tried way you described me and it work, but I hoped in more elegant way e.g service.. Nevermind